# System Verilog randomize address equal to 2 to the power off

Tags: constraints, verilog, system-verilog

I want to constrain an address in System Verilog so that the address is equal to two the power of value. for example the generated address(16-bit) should be

addr = 0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 .... 32,768

The following works for me. However, I am looking for any other short and elegant way of doing it.

```
class two_power_addr;
  rand bit [15:0] addr;
  bit [15:0] temp;

  constraint c_addr {
    addr == temp;
  }

endclass

module tb();
  two_power_addr c;

  initial begin
    c=new();
    c.temp=0;
    c.randomize();
    $display("%0d \n", c.addr);
    c.temp=16'h2;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) begin      
      c.randomize();
      c.temp=c.temp<<1;
      $display("%0d \n", c.addr);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constraint c_addr { $onehot0(addr) == 1; }
```

Comment: this will not work since the system call sometimes won't work on different compilers. It would be much useful if you could provide a general way to write this constraint

Comment: I've tried my solution on 4 different simulators and it works on all of them. You can always revert back to shifting 'b1 by a random value.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your constraint as follow to check whether the randomized value is of 2's power or not.

```
constraint 2_power {
  (addr != 0) -> (addr & (addr - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Her is a variant without constrains and classes  which works perfectly well in your case.

```
 bit[3:0] rnd;
 logic address[15:0];

 rnd =  $urandom;
 address = 16'b1 << rnd;
```

I guess you can come up with a class randomization for `rnd` if you wish instead of $urandom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more alternative method to do same. Also I prefer Dave's method more as it is short, power of two can never be 0 so `$onehot0` can be replaced by `$onehot`. But as the question included `addr = 0`, in that case `$onehot0` can be used.

```
class gen#(parameter width = 8);

    rand bit [width-1:0] addr;
    rand int num;
  
    constraint num_c { num inside {[0:width-1]};}
    constraint pow_2 {  addr == 2**num;}

endclass: gen
```